# Do bind variables optimize query performance in MS-Access?

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, ms-access-2007

Bind variables are key to application performance on Oracle DBMS (skips hardparsing)

But as I am unaware of MS-Access parsing logic, will it work for MS-Access 2007?

My Application heavily uses SQL queries which are hardcoded right at this moment. The application works with other binary files also, with a normal execution times of 12-14 hours.. As I am stuck with this this tool tight release along with performance improvements, I will greatly thankful for any guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think MS Access doesn't have a mechanism for caching execution plan of queries
executed.

So I recommend to read articles like [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/889588) to optimize your application

Also read
https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-5064388.html and
[Jet Engine's query-optimization is based on statistics, but how are they refreshed with linked tables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1703811/jet-engines-query-optimization-is-based-on-statistics-but-how-are-they-refreshe)

Comment: "doesn't have a mechanism for caching execution plan" = correct (in context).

Comment: "doesn't build any execution plan": incorrect: google "showplan.out".

Comment: "doesn't have any query optimization engine" = incorrect: you seem to be saying that Access (ACE, Jet, whatever) doesn't have an optimizer, which is absurd.

Comment: @onedaywhen Thank you pal for enlightenment

Comment: I'm not sure the initial point is entirely correct either, as Jet/ACE stores compiled query plans for dynamic SQL, depending on where it is used. It won't do it for SQL executed in code, though, but in a lot of other contexts, it will.